# Trying to visualize Time Complexity by plotting graph, unexpected output

Tags: python, time, time-complexity

I have defined a simple funcion that computes sum of elements of a list. It is of linear complexity. I tried as below to visualize the graph(X axis for n=no of elements in the list, Y axis for time taken to compute sum of elements in the list with n elements):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
code_to_test='''

def find_sum(input_list):
    total =0
    for i in input_list:           
        total +=i
    return total

'''

X=[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]

Y=[]

for n in X:
    input_list=list(range(n))  
    elapsed_time=timeit.timeit(code_to_test, number=1000)/1000
    Y.append(elapsed_time)

print(len(Y))

plt.plot(X,Y)
```

The graphical output is not linear. Also, the output is varying every time I rerun.
I am using Macbook Pro and have many chrome windows with many tabs open with youtube links but all are paused.  Is this impacting the graph or I am missing something in plotting?

Comment: try making the X values much larger, maybe up to 1000, and if the speed is too slow, then lower the 1000 constant (how many times to run the function)

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything, it simply defines a function, `code_to_test` but never calls it.

Comment: @MaisyDoge13: Tried your suggestion with X=[50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900], also, reduced 1000 to 100, but no difference :(

Comment: @anz I already explained to you, your `X` does nothing and has no affect on the code you are timing, which simply defines a function and never calls it.